# Typescript module not loading after compile

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

New to Angular/ts/js. I went through the Tour of Heroes tutorial, now I am trying to incorporate compiling and building via gulp. Seems to be going well enough but I can't seem to figure this roadblock out.

In a single example, I have the app/components/app.module.ts file (disregard the deep relative import pathing; I plan on refactoring it later):

```
import { BrowserModule } from '../../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '../../node_modules/@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '../../node_modules/@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '../../node_modules/@angular/http';

import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from '../../node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService } from './in-memory-data.service';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail.component';
import { HeroSearchComponent } from './hero-search.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpModule,
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService, { delay: 600 })
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    HeroSearchComponent,
    HeroesComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent,
  ],
  providers: [HeroService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

After I compile it to js and serve up the application, the console tells me:

> "Cannot GET /js/components/app.component"

(along with all the other modules after it), even though that js DOES exist at the location.

I believe I found that it's still expecting it to be the ts file. If I explicitly change the import to be a js file as

```
"import { AppComponent } from './app.component.js';"
```

then it loads fine.

In my research, I think I may need a sourcemap, but being entirely green at this I'm not sure. I'm not entirely sure how to describe/define the issue so web searches haven't netted me anything definitive. Can someone get me on the right track?

**Update**
Here is my gulpfile. Still learning so I know it's messy.

```
// grab our packages
var gulp   = require('gulp'),
    jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
    clean = require('gulp-clean'),
    connect = require('gulp-connect'),
    gnf = require('gulp-npm-files');

const tscConfig = require('./tsconfig.json');

var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var merge = require('merge2');

// define the default task and add the watch task to it
gulp.task('default', ['watch']);

// configure the jshint task
gulp.task('jshint', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/components/js/**/*.js')
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'));
});

// configure which files to watch and what tasks to use on file changes
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('app/components/js/**/*.js', ['jshint']);
});


gulp.task('compileTs', function () {
  var tsResult = gulp.src('app/**/*.ts')
      .pipe(ts({
          declaration: true
      }));

  return merge([
      tsResult.dts.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/definitions')),
      tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'))
  ]);
});

gulp.task('compileEnviroTs', function () {
  var tsResult = gulp.src('environments/**/*.ts')
      .pipe(ts({
          declaration: true
      }));

  return merge([
      tsResult.dts.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/definitions')),
      tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/environments'))
  ]);
});



gulp.task('cleanDist', function() {
  return gulp.src('dist', {read: false})
    .pipe(clean());
});


gulp.task('copyDeps', ['cleanDist'], function() {
  gulp
    .src(gnf(null, './package.json'), {base:'./'})
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});


gulp.task('copyEnvironments', ['copyDeps'], function() {
  return gulp.src('environments/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/environments'));
});

gulp.task('copyComponents', ['copyEnvironments'], function() {
  return gulp.src('app/components/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/components'));
});

gulp.task('copyCss', ['copyComponents'], function() {
  return gulp.src('app/css/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));
});

gulp.task('copyImg', ['copyCss'], function() {
  return gulp.src('app/img/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img'));
});

gulp.task('copyJs', ['copyImg'], function() {
  return gulp.src('app/js/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});

gulp.task('copyPartials', ['copyJs'], function() {
  return gulp.src('app/partials/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/partials'));
});

gulp.task('copyFiles', ['copyPartials'], function() {
  return gulp.src('app/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});


gulp.task('connect', ['copyFiles', 'compileTs'], function () {
  connect.server({
    root: 'dist/',
    port: 8888
  });
});


gulp.task('dev', ['cleanDist', 'compileTs', 'compileEnviroTs', 'copyDeps', 'copyFiles', 'connect']);
```

**Update**
Here is my code repo, if it helps any. I'm in the gulp branch.
https://github.com/fmjnax/LearningAngular.git

Comment: If possible please share your gulpfile.

Comment: Updated the orig post to include the gulpfile